# calculate the limit of the sequence: $a_{n}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{k^{2n}+k^{n}+3}{4^{n}+k^{2n}}},k>0,n\epsilon N^{*}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

can somebody help to calculate the limit of this sequence and explain?
$a_{n}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{k^{2n}+k^{n}+3}{4^{n}+k^{2n}}},k>0,n\epsilon N^{*}$

Comment: ...What have you tried so far?

Comment: to take out the common factor k^n and generally to simplify it but i didnt get anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint: $\log a_{n}=\log\sqrt[n]{\frac{k^{2n}+k^{n}+3}{4^{n}+k^{2n}}}= \frac{1}{n } \log\frac{k^{2n}+k^{n}+3}{4^{n}+k^{2n}}$**

Answer (score 0):

take 3 cases $ 0<k<2, k = 2, k>2$

$k\geq 2$

$(4/k^2)^n \to 0 , n \to \infty $. Divide given expression by $k^{2n}$, we get 1 as limit value

$ k<2 $ apply log, and l'hospital's rule